# Confusion about curved exponential family in Casella & Berger

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

In Definition 3.4.7 of Statistical Inference by Casella & Berger, 2nd ed., a *curved exponential family* is defined to be a family of the form

$$
f(x \vert \boldsymbol\theta) = h(x)c(\boldsymbol\theta)\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}w_i(\boldsymbol\theta)t_i(x)\right)
$$

for which the dimension of the vector $\boldsymbol\theta$ is equal to $d<k$. A normal $n(\theta, \theta)$ (i.e. mean and variance are both $\theta$) is used in problem 3.33 and in Example 3.4.9 as an example of a curved exponential family. But I'm having trouble seeing why this is a curved family. Since there is only one parameter, $d=1$. Working out the form of the exponential family to which this belongs, I get

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}\exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\exp(x)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\theta}\right)
$$

so that $h(x) = \exp(x)$, $c(\theta) = \frac{\exp\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}$, and $w_1(\theta) = -1/2\theta$, $t_1(x) = x^2$. In that case, $k=1$. So we have a situation where $d=k$, which does not meet the condition for a curved exponential family according to the above definition. I'm confused about why the text considers it a curved family in Example 3.4.9 and Exercise 3.33(a). Can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2):

Exercise 3.33 doesn't ask you to verify that the family is a *curved* exponential family, it only asks you to verify that the family is exponential. You are correct in that your calculation shows that $N(\theta, \theta)$ is a *full* exponential family (the second part of Definition 3.4.7). Here's a screenshot of the exercise in question.

[image]

By asking you to describe the curve on which the parameter vector lies, the authors mean the ray $(\theta, \theta)$ for all $\theta > 0$.

A second, minor point is that you've also dropped a sign in your derivation, which follows.

$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \theta}} \exp\left( - \frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2 \theta}\right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \theta} } \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2 \theta} + x + -\frac{\theta}{2} \right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \theta} } \exp(x) \exp(-\frac{\theta}{2}) \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2 \theta}  \right).$$

**UPDATE**: The OPs question was more subtle than I gave it credit for. See the comments below for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the correction! I am still a bit confused because, in problem 6.25(b), the same distribution arises. But based on the problem statement, it seems like they are saying the family is curved and that the open set condition of Theorem 6.2.25 is not satisfied. However, since k=1, it seems to me like the condition is satisfied, since any open interval in the nonnegative real line will do. I also referenced Example 3.4.9, for which they refer to it as a curved exponential family.

Comment: In my text, example 3.4.9 is $N(\lambda, \lambda/n)$, so the mean and variance are not equal for this example. For problem 6.25(b), note that the (claimed) minimal sufficient statistic is a vector of length 1. This is an important distinction. Note that the combination of Theorems 6.2.25 and 6.2.28 gives that the minimal sufficient statistic is 1D. All this follows from your expression of the family with $k=d=1$.

Comment: Thanks. My text has the example yours does, but I think my point still stands. The example is a 1-parameter exponential family, but just like the $n(\theta, \theta)$ case, when we work out the form of the exponential family we get k=1. So how can it be a curved family?

Comment: I agree that this is confusing. The authors seem to be using some conflicting ideas here. On one hand, the definition is what it is. But in the miscellenea (p 138), the authors write that "Cases where [the parameter space] is a low dimensional subset of [the largest possible parameter space] give rise to curved exponential families". So I don't know what to make of it; these examples are exp. fams. by the 2nd definition but not the first. So, my answer may be contrary to the authors' intent. I guess they mean to suggest that $\frac{x n \lambda}{\lambda}$  should be left unreduced?

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to look into this. I would guess, based on the section you referenced in miscellanea, that the authors may have used a simplified definition of a curved exponential family for this text. But that leads to some confusion. Maybe someone else will have some input. Otherwise, if I happen to find a concrete explanation for this some day I'll follow up here. Thanks again!